# Reaction of Mg/Hg amalgam with acetophenone

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image: enter image description here here]

Will Mg perform here as Grignard or will something else happen?

Comment: Note the presence of the Hg, this will not be a simple Grignard. There is a clue here http://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV1P0459

Comment: @Poutnik new to this sir. I have edited, is this fine

Comment: @DUDE_WITH_J   have a read of this   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinacol_rearrangement

Comment: @Waylander sure sir , will read it thanks for your effort !

Comment: It helps to write in full clear sentences. I reopened but please note it is expected that you show what it is makes the solution unclear.

Comment: ...and the [pinacol coupling reaction](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/pinacol-coupling) and [migratory aptitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Migratory_aptitude).

Comment: @BuckThorn ok sirr I will remember it and Can I ask theory related Q

Comment: If it's a very closely related question it might be better to continue in chat. If your questions are repeatedly poorly received the system robot might impose a temporary ban on your ability to start more posts.